# How to iterate functions over each file in a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have codes that works for one specified file. How to iterate the same function for multiple files?

The code below works for test3.txt file. I have multiple files in a folder (test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt ...) Can you please help me iterate over each file? I believe I have to change **lines 6-7**. Please help. I am new to python...

```
import os,csv,datefinder,re
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article')

with open("test3.txt", 'r') as file1:
      text1=file1.read()

#locate the date of the article
matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text1))

if len(matches) > 0:
    date=matches[1]
    strdate = str(date)

else:
    print 'No dates found'


#locate the name of the company
matchcomp = re.search(r'Keywords:([^,]*)(,|$)', text1).group(1).strip()

#count the number of words in the article
matchcount = re.search(r'(.*) words', text1).group(1).strip()

#determine the article
def matchwho():
    if 'This story was generated by' in text1:
        return('1')
    elif 'This story includes elements generated' in text1:
        return('2')
    elif 'Elements of this story were generated' in text1:
        return('2')
    elif 'Portions of this story were generated' in text1:
        return('2')
    else:
        return('3')

matchw =str(matchwho())

#list the returns in a line
combid = matchcomp + "," + strdate + "," + matchw + "," + matchcount

#save in txt format
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(combid)
```

I would expect the returns to append in a outfile.txt

Comment: you can use `os.walk()` (or more likely `os.dir()` here) to return all the filenames within the folder. Then bundle all your code you have into some function like `def match_from_file(file)` and pass your filenames into that function

Comment: @Reedinationer will os.dir() repeat the function for all text files in the folder? I tried, but it just didn't work....

Comment: My apologies I put the wrong command (`dir` is for command prompt). You can try `files = os.listdir()` and then if you want to process ALL the files you can do `for file in files: print(file)` or maybe you want to add `if ".txt" in file:` so you only grab the text files in that folder. `os.walk()` will let you gather all files within a folder recursively, so if all your files are tucked away in a series of folders you can use that instead

Comment: @Reedinationer the problem is, despite using os.listdir(), my lines 6-7 already specifies "test3.txt" in it. Wouldn't that prohibit the os.listdir() from reading through all text files in a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to package all your code into a function that can be called many times for each file

```
import os,csv,datefinder,re
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article')

def matchwho(text_to_match):
    if 'This story was generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('1')
    elif 'This story includes elements generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'Elements of this story were generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'Portions of this story were generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    else:
        return('3')


def extract_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file1:
        text1=file1.read()
    #locate the date of the article
    matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text1))
    if len(matches) > 0:
        date=matches[1]
        strdate = str(date)
    else:
        print 'No dates found'
    #locate the name of the company
    matchcomp = re.search(r'Keywords:([^,]*)(,|$)', text1).group(1).strip()
    #count the number of words in the article
    matchcount = re.search(r'(.*) words', text1).group(1).strip()
    #determine the article
    matchw =str(matchwho(text1))
    #list the returns in a line
    combid = matchcomp + "," + strdate + "," + matchw + "," + matchcount
    #save in txt format
    with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(combid)

files = os.listdir()
for file in files:
    if ".txt" in file:
        extract_data(file)
```

*Note I did not test this code because I don't have the .txt files you are processing. There may be errors, but I think it showcases how to grab file names and feed them to a processing function. If this solved your problem it'd be great if you can click the check mark by the post :)

Answer (score 0):

first move everything from line 6 on into a new function called `process_file` or so, which gets a a parameter `filename` and then replace `text3.txt` in this function by `filename`

Now you can write at the end of your script

```py
for f in os.listdir('C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article'):
    process_file(f)
```

This will do the job.